# iPad App doesn't open on Retina Display iPads but do open on older iPads

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I am using latest XCode 5.1.1 and developed a new iPad App in XCode.

The problem is that it doesn't open in Retina Display iPads but does open in older iPads ... In Simulator it opens in all perfectly.

Any idea why it is happening?

### Following are my details.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: When you say open? You mean it launches and then crashes or just doesn't open?

Comment: Your deployment target is set to 6.0. Are you running on an iPad that is running an earlier version of that?

Comment: It proceeds on installing, but doesn't start the install. I am doing AdHoc Deployment on selected iPads.

Comment: Check the device log, I'm sure that this will shed some light on the issue.

Comment: May be, but I guess Retina should be above than 6.0 ... Any idea how can I add more Deployment Targets?

Comment: The only suspicious thing I see in Logs is this `Started backup to iCloud! Please be careful.
Your application might rejected by Apple if you store too much data.
`

Comment: You can add more deployment target just by clicking the dropdown menu next to deployment target. You should see a list of options for different OS versions. You can change it from there.

Comment: I don't have lower than 6.0

Comment: Can you tell me the iPad OS version: setting>general>about>verison (Do this on the iPad that your is is not working on)